# SPARQL query in DBpedia Sorql return no results

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia

I tried to run SPARQL query from the book Learning SPARQL of Bob DuCharme. I runned it on `http://dbpedia.org/snorql`:

```
SELECT ?elvisbday WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elvis_Presley> 
  <http://dbpedia.org/property/dateOfBirth> ?elvisbday .
}
```

But the result is an empty output. I checked that URIs are correct. So what's my error? Do I need to add some specific PREFIX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the property wrong. Try this:

```
SELECT  ?elvisbday WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elvis_Presley> 
  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?elvisbday .
}
```

In the future, you might want to explore the properties that describe the resource in the endoint if you don't find what you are looking for. You may use this query for that:

```
SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elvis_Presley> ?p ?o
}
```

Comment: Note that there *is* a dbp property too, but it's `dbp:birthDate`, not `dbp:dateOfBirth`.